# How to disable the Cron scheduler based on the deployed environment?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a spring boot application with Cron scheduler.
we have to change the **spring.enable.scheduling** key in property file as true or false based on deployed environment. Here we are using Elastic beanStalk environment.
Our Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN mkdir -p  /usr/local/upload/temp
COPY target/sample.jar /usr/app/sample.jar
WORKDIR /usr/app
EXPOSE 10032
#RUN sh -c 'touch sample.jar'
#CMD /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true
CMD /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -jar /usr/app/sample.jar
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) to have different config files per environment.

Or, you can just pass the environment variable `SPRING_ENABLE_SCHEDULING="false"` to the docker container when you start it in those environments. See the documentation on overriding spring properties via environment variables [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables). I see you are using Elastic Beanstalk, so you would [configure that as a environment properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console) in the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: @NickODell there is absolutely no need for that here. That sets environment variables for the docker build stage, which is not at all related to the issue being asked. The question is about overriding a setting at run time (and only in specific environments, so it shouldn't be hard-coded in the docker image anyway).